#  compare adjacent elements of the same vector (avoiding loops)

Tags: r, vector, string-comparison, sapply

I managed to write a `for loop` to compare letters in the following vector:

```
bases <- c("G","C","A","T")
test <- sample(bases, replace=T, 20)
```

`test` will return

```
[1] "T" "G" "T" "G" "C" "A" "A" "G" "A" "C" "A" "T" "T" "T" "T" "C" "A" "G" "G" "C"
```

with the function `Comp()` I can check if a letter is matching to the next letter

```
Comp <- function(data)
{
    output <- vector()
    for(i in 1:(length(data)-1))
    {
    if(data[i]==data[i+1])
        {
        output[i] <-1
        }
        else
        {
        output[i] <-0
        }
    }
    return(output)
}
```

Resulting in;

```
> Comp(test)
 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0
```

This is working, however its verry slow with large numbers. Therefor i tried `sapply()`

```
Comp <- function(x,i) if(x[i]==x[i+1]) 1 else 0
unlist(lapply(test, Comp, test))
```

Unfortunately its not working... (`Error in i + 1 : non-numeric argument to binary operator`) I have trouble figuring out how to access the preceding letter in the vector to compare it. Also the `length(data)-1`, to "not compare" the last letter might become a problem.

Thank you all for the help!

Cheers
Lucky

Comment: I reworded the title to illustrate the problem better and for reference purposes. You should also be aware that sapply/lapply etc. *are* loops, albeit in a different form. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275896/is-rs-apply-family-more-than-syntactic-sugar

Comment: Thank you, im new to R and programming und not that familiar with the terms

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just "lag" `test` and use `==`, which is vectorized.

```
bases <- c("G","C","A","T")
set.seed(21)
test <- sample(bases, replace=TRUE, 20)
lag.test <- c(tail(test,-1),NA)
#lag.test <- c(NA,head(test,-1))
test == lag.test
```

Update:

Also, your `Comp` function is slow because you don't specify the length of `output` when you initialize it.  I suspect you were trying to pre-allocate, but `vector()` creates a zero-length vector that must be expanded during every iteration of your loop.  Your `Comp` function is significantly faster if you change the call to `vector()` to `vector(length=NROW(data)-1)`.

```
set.seed(21)
test <- sample(bases, replace=T, 1e5)
system.time(orig <- Comp(test))
#    user  system elapsed 
#  34.760   0.010  34.884 
system.time(prealloc <- Comp.prealloc(test))
#    user  system elapsed 
#    1.18    0.00    1.19 
identical(orig, prealloc)
# [1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 3):

As @Joshua wrote, you should of course use vectorization - it is way more efficient. 
...But just for reference, your `Comp` function can still be optimized a bit.

The result of a comparison is `TRUE/FALSE` which is glorified versions of `1/0`. Also, ensuring the result is integer instead of numeric consumes half the memory.

```
Comp.opt <- function(data)
{
    output <- integer(length(data)-1L)
    for(i in seq_along(output))
    {
        output[[i]] <- (data[[i]]==data[[i+1L]])
    }
    return(output)
}
```

...and the speed difference:

```
> system.time(orig <- Comp(test))
   user  system elapsed 
  21.10    0.00   21.11 
> system.time(prealloc <- Comp.prealloc(test))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.49    0.00    0.49 
> system.time(opt <- Comp.opt(test))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.41    0.00    0.40 
> all.equal(opt, orig) # opt is integer, orig is double
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this :

```
> x = c("T", "G", "T", "G", "G","T","T","T")
> 
> res = sequence(rle(x)$lengths)-1
> 
> dt = data.frame(x,res)
> 
> dt
  x res
1 T   0
2 G   0
3 T   0
4 G   0
5 G   1
6 T   0
7 T   1
8 T   2
```

Might work faster.