# vectorising the application of mle2 models

Tags: r, statistics, plyr

I have written a model that I am fitting to data using ML via the mle2 package. However, I have a large data frame of samples and I would like to fit the model to each replicate, and then retrieve all of the coefficients of the model in a data frame.

I have tried to use the ddply function in the plyr package with no success.

I get the following error message when I try:

```
Error in output[[var]][rng] <- df[[var]] : 
  incompatible types (from S4 to logical) in subassignment type fix
```

Any thoughts?

here is an example of what I am doing.

This is my data frame. I have measurement in `Pond` 5...n on `day` 1....n. Measurements consist of 143 fluxes (`flux.cor`), which is the variable I am modelling.

```
     Pond Obs                Date     Time   Temp       DO   pH U day month    PAR
932    5 932 2011-06-16 17:31:00 17:31:00 294.05 334.3750 8.47 2   1     1 685.08
933    5 933 2011-06-16 17:41:00 17:41:00 294.05 339.0625 8.47 2   1     1 808.44
934    5 934 2011-06-16 17:51:00 17:51:00 294.02 340.6250 8.46 2   1     1 752.78
935    5 935 2011-06-16 18:01:00 18:01:00 294.00 340.6250 8.45 2   1     1 684.14
936    5 936 2011-06-16 18:11:00 18:11:00 293.94 340.9375 8.50 2   1     1 625.86
937    5 937 2011-06-16 18:21:00 18:21:00 293.88 341.5625 8.48 2   1     1 597.06
    day.night Treat            H  pOH           OH   DO.cor   sd.DO    av.DO   DO.sat
932         1     A 3.388442e-09 5.53 2.951209e-06 342.1406 2.63078 342.1406 274.0811
933         1     A 3.388442e-09 5.53 2.951209e-06 339.0625 2.63078 342.1406 274.0811
934         1     A 3.467369e-09 5.54 2.884032e-06 340.6250 2.63078 342.1406 274.2432
935         1     A 3.548134e-09 5.55 2.818383e-06 340.6250 2.63078 342.1406 274.3513
936         1     A 3.162278e-09 5.50 3.162278e-06 340.9375 2.63078 342.1406 274.6763
937         1     A 3.311311e-09 5.52 3.019952e-06 341.5625 2.63078 342.1406 275.0020
      DO_flux      NEP.hr  flux.cor  sd.flux    av.flux
932 -3.078125 -3.09222602 -3.078125 2.104482 -0.1070312
933  1.562500  1.54903673  1.562500 2.104482 -0.1070312
934  0.000000 -0.01375489  0.000000 2.104482 -0.1070312
935  0.312500  0.29876654  0.312500 2.104482 -0.1070312
936  0.625000  0.61126617  0.625000 2.104482 -0.1070312
```

here is the my model:

```
    # function that generates predictions of O2 flux given GPP R and gas exchange
flux.pred <- function(GPP24, PAR, R24, Temp, U, DO, DOsat){
    # calculates Schmidt coefficient from water temperature
    Sc<-function(Temp){
        S<-0.0476*(Temp)^2 + 3.7818*(Temp)^2 - 120.1*Temp + 1800.6
        }
    # calculates piston velocity k (m h-1) from wind speed at 10m (m s-1)
    k600<-function(U){
        k.600<-(2.07 + 0.215*((U)^1.7))/100 
        }
    # calculates piston velocity k (m h-1) from wind speed at 10m (m s-1)
    k<-function(Temp,U){
        k<-k600(U)*((Sc(Temp)/600)^-0.5)
        }
    # physical gas flux (mg O2 m-2 10mins-1)
    D<-function(Temp,U,DO,DOsat){
        d<-(k(Temp,U)/6)*(DO-DOsat)
    }   

  # main function to generate predictions   
flux<-(GPP24/sum(YSI$PAR[YSI$PAR>40]))*(ifelse(YSI$PAR>40, YSI$PAR, 0))-(R24/144)+D(YSI$Temp,YSI$U,YSI$DO,YSI$DO.sat)
return(flux)
}
```

which returns predictions for the fluxes.

I then build my likelihood function:

```
   # likelihood function
ll<-function(GPP24, PAR, R24, Temp, U, DO.cor, DO.sat){
    pred = (flux.pred(GPP24, PAR, R24, Temp, U, DO.cor, DOsat))
    pred = pred[-144]
    obs = YSI$flux.cor[-144]
    return(-sum(dnorm(obs, mean=pred, sd=sqrt(var(obs-pred)))))
    }
```

and apply it

ll.fit<-mle2(ll,start=list(GPP24=100, R24=100))

It works beautifully for one Pond on one day, but what I want to do is apply it to all ponds on all days automatically.

I tried the ddply (as stated above)

```
metabolism<-ddply(YSI, .(Pond,Treat,day,month), summarise,
mle = mle2(ll,start=list(GPP24=100, R24=100)))
```

but had not success. I also tried just extracting the coefficients using a for loop, but this did not work either.

```
for(i in 1:length(unique(YSI$day))){
GPP<-numeric(length=length(unique(YSI$day)))
GPP[i]<-mle2(ll,start=list(GPP24=100, R24=100))
    }
```

any help would be gratefully received.

Comment: I think you are going to have to show us a reproducible example as it is very difficult to know exactly what you are doing.

Comment: You're going to have to rethink your strategy here: since you are not passing your data.frame (YSI) to method ll, but using the variable from the global environment, ddply has no way of 'subsetting' it. ddply works (an oversimplification, but a workable one) by subsetting the data.frame and passing the subsets _as a parameter_ to the function provided.

Comment: Do you want `dlply`?  I don't see how you can shoehorn mle2 objects into a data frame.

Comment: what else do you suggest? how can I repeatedly assign mle2 to data. Surely there must be a more efficient method than just manually running the model 1...n times?

Comment: I don't have time for a full solution to this (especially since the data are not provided in a particularly convenient form -- try `dput` next time ...), but I will point out that the `mle2` function takes a `data` argument, and attempts to evaluate the negative log-likelihood function in an environment that includes the data ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's at least one problem with your functions : Nowhere in your function flux.pred or ll do you have an argument where you can actually specify what the data is that is used. You hardcoded it. So how on earth is any *ply supposed to guess that it needs to change `YSI$...` into a subset?

Next to that, as @hadley points out, ddply will not suit you. `dlply` might, or you might just use the classic approach of either `by()` or `lapply(split())`.

So imagine you make a function

```
flux.pred <- function(data, GPP24, R24){
    # calculates Schmidt coefficient from water temperature
    Sc<-function(data$Temp){
        S<-0.0476*(data$Temp)^2 ...
    ...
    }
```

and a function

```
ll<-function(GPP24, R24, data ){
    pred = (flux.pred(data, GPP24, R24 ))
    pred = pred[-144] # check this
    obs = data$flux.cor[-144] # check this
    return(-sum(dnorm(obs, mean=pred, sd=sqrt(var(obs-pred)))))
    }
```

You should then be able to do do eg :

```
dlply(data, .(Pond,Treat,day,month), .fun=function(i){
    mle2(ll,start=list(GPP24=100, R24=100, data=i))
})
```

The passing of the data argument is dependent on what you use in mle2 for the optimization. In your case, you use the default optimizer, which is `optim`. See `?optim` for more details. The argument `data=i` will be passed from `mle2` to `optim` to `ll`.

What I can't check, is how the optim behaves. It might even be that your function doesn't really work as you intend. Normally you should have a function ll like :

```
ll <- function(par, data){
    GPP24 <- par[1]
    R24 <- par[2]
    ...
}
```

for optim to work. But if you say it works as you wrote it, I believe you. Make sure though it actually does. I am not convinced...

On a sidenote : neither using `by()` / `lapply(split())` nor using `dlply()` is the same as vectorizing. In contrary, all these constructs are intrinsic loops. On the why of using them, read : [Is R's apply family more than syntactic sugar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275896/is-rs-apply-family-more-than-syntactic-sugar)

Comment: PS : the [-144] is to cut out a wrong value I guess. Don't do it that way! get it out of the way and work with cleaned data (make sure you saved your original dataframe first).

Comment: Thanks for the help all. I will amend. Much appreciated. And apologies for the poor terminology. I am relatively new to this game.