# Using Apply in R so that string (x) generates string (z) which is used to perform an operation with string (y)

Tags: r, string

I'm trying to use *apply* (and avoid a *for* loop) to run the pair of operations below on a dataframe using values from two different strings.  The strings and the dataframe I'm working with look like this:

```
x <- c("A", "B", "C")
y <- c(1, 3, 4)

df:
var1  var2
ddAd  NA
dBdd  NA
ddCd  NA
```

I'm trying to run the following two lines of code for each pair of values in the two strings using *apply*.

```
z <- grep(x, df$var1, value = FALSE)
df[z, 3] <- y
```

The end result I'm going for is this:

```
var1  var2
ddAd  1
dBdd  3
ddCd  4
```

My attempts to use *apply* so far seem to work fine with the first line of code, but I run into trouble with the second line.  I think I need to run an *apply* command within an *apply* command in this situation, but I haven't been able to get that to work.  Can anyone show me how to use "apply" in this situation?  Thanks!

Comment: Apply doesn't necessarily means performance gain. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275896/is-rs-apply-family-more-than-syntactic-sugar) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7638095/r-confusion-with-apply-vs-for-loop). It's the vectorization really speed things up, and you need to avoid some common mistakes could happen in for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `paste` the 'x' `vector` into a single string and use as `pattern` in the `grep`

```
z <- grep(paste(x, collapse="|"), df$var1, value = FALSE)
```

and use the index to reorder the 'y' and assign it to 'var2'

```
df$var2 <- y[z]
df
#  var1 var2
#1 ddAd    1
#2 dBdd    3
#3 ddCd    4
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply @akrun !  It's much more elegant than the approach I was trying.  I have just one more question about your approach: is there a way to make this work if vector 'x' doesn't have an exhaustive list of the names in the df's var1 column?

Comment: Here's an example of what I mean:
The 'x' and 'y' vectors stay the same, but the df has one more row: "ddDd  NA".  Is there a way to run your suggested operation so that the var2 values that are returned are "1, 3, 4, NA"?

Comment: @R.Buchanan  Perhaps `df$var2[z] <- y[z]`

Comment: As @akrun points out in a separate thread, `df$var2[z] <- y` is the correct operation.  `df$var2[z] <- y[z]` doesn't work as intended.

Comment: @R.Buchanan  Thanks for the clarification.