# R-language: function to process data in data frame

Tags: r

The scenario is that there is a function which takes values from columns in a data frame, does some processing and populates another column with the results.

Here is a simplified version for testing:

```
#the function checks if the value in inVar1 exists.
#if it does then it returns the value, if not it returns -100
#inRow: for debugging
test2 <- function (inVar1,inRow)
 {
  #debug
  print(paste("Row=",inRow, " inVar1=", inVar1, sep=''))

  if(is.na(inVar1) || is.null(inVar1))
   {
    #debug
    print("position 1")

    ret <- -100
   }
  else
   {
    #debug
    print("position 2")

    ret <- inVar1
   }

  #debug
  print("position 3")

  return(ret)
 }
```

simple function tests:

```
> a <- test2(7,1)
[1] "Row=1 inVar1=7"
[1] "position 2"
[1] "position 3"
> print(a)
[1] 7
> 
> a <- test2(NA,1)
[1] "Row=1 inVar1=NA"
[1] "position 1"
[1] "position 3"
> print(a)
[1] -100
```

It works as expected.

Now let's create a data frame

```
> d1 <- data.frame(rowID=c(1,2,3), var1=c(2,NA,5))
> print(d1)
  rowID var1
1     1    2
2     2   NA
3     3    5
```

Let's test the function passing values from the data frame:

```
> a <- test2(d1[1,2],d1[1,1])
[1] "Row=1 inVar1=2"
[1] "position 2"
[1] "position 3"
> print(a)               
[1] 2
> a <- test2(d1[2,2],d1[2,1])
[1] "Row=2 inVar1=NA"
[1] "position 1"
[1] "position 3"
> print(a)               
[1] -100
> a <- test2(d1[3,2],d1[3,1])
[1] "Row=3 inVar1=5"
[1] "position 2"
[1] "position 3"
> print(a)
[1] 5
```

Again, it works as expected.

Now, the final thing. I want to add a new column with the processed values.

```
d1$var2 <- test2(d1$var1,d1$rowID)
print(d1)
```

This produces the following output:

```
> d1$var2 <- test2(d1$var1,d1$rowID)
[1] "Row=1 inVar1=2"  "Row=2 inVar1=NA" "Row=3 inVar1=5" 
[1] "position 2"
[1] "position 3"
> print(d1)
  rowID var1 var2
1     1    2    2
2     2   NA   NA
3     3    5    5
```

The values for var2 in rows 1 and 3 computed as expected but in row 2 it's NA instead of expected -100.

What do I do wrong?

Another thing I don't understand is why we see debug messages only once, but not according to the number of rows, i.e. thrice?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your function isn't vectorized. You pass 1 pair of numbers 3 times, one for each row and it's correct, while your final test passes 1 pair of vectors once; 1 vector for each variable. In order for your function to work, you need to feed it 1 pair at a time. mapply will do that for you.

```
d1$var2 <- mapply(FUN = test2,inVar1 = d1$var1,inRow = d1$rowID)
```

But overall, you probably need to rewrite your function with vectorization in mind.

```
# "vectorised in the sense that it can operate on entire vectors at once"
test2vectbasic <- function(inVar1,inRow){
  # using mapply, but could be a basic for loop too
  mapply(FUN = test2,inVar1 = inVar1,inRow = inRow)
}

# efficient R vectorization that uses built in low level language loops
# using "existing R functions that are already vectorised"
test2vectbetter <- function(inVar1){
  ifelse(is.na(inVar1) | is.null(inVar1),-100,inVar1)
}

# sample data
d1 <- data.frame(rowID=c(1,2,3), var1=c(2,NA,5))

# mapply way
d1$var2 <- mapply(FUN = test2,inVar1 = d1$var1,inRow = d1$rowID)

# basic way on atoms or vectors
test2vectbasic(d1[2,2],d1[2,1])
d1$var3 <- test2vectbasic(d1$var1,d1$rowID)

# efficient way
test2vectbetter(d1[2,2],d1[2,1])
d1$var4 <- test2vectbetter(d1$var1)
```

To get the functionality you want, you'll need at least basic vectorization. A couple resources about vectorization:

[how-to-define-a-vectorized-function-in-r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11965515/how-to-define-a-vectorized-function-in-r)

[R inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf) - go to the third circle of Hell - Failing to Vectorize

Comment: Thank you ARobertson, it works! As to "rewrite function with vectorization in mind" could you please give a simple example?

Comment: So the way is to create a wrapper around my function where I use the mapply() instead of using mapply() as an outer function in order to run my test2().
Thank you again ARobertson!