# Is there an easy way to know which functions vectorize and which do not?

Tags: r

I am puzzled by the difference in behaviour between these 2 functions. Basically, f1 vectorizes nicely while f2 doesn't.

```
f1 <- function(x,y) {
  list(sqrt(x),sqrt(y))
}

f1(iris[[1]],iris[[2]])

f2 <- function(x,y) {
  list(rbinom(1, as.integer(x), 0.5),rbinom(1, as.integer(y), 0.5))
}

f2(iris[[1]],iris[[2]])
```

Is there a way to know (or guess ...) which functions vectorize and which do not? Other than testing of course.

Thanks

Comment: It is the functions behavior of output.  Here, in `f2`, you want to get n = 1 because the `size` is dependent on each element value, while `sqrt` is already vectorized

Comment: Related/Duplicate - [How to define a vectorized function in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11965515/how-to-define-a-vectorized-function-in-r)

Comment: `rbinom` (and the other functions for random sampling from distributions) is vectorized, but it explicitly takes the length of the result as an argument.  This will work: `list(rbinom(length(x), as.integer(x), 0.5), rbinom(length(y), as.integer(y), 0.5))`

Comment: Even functions that are vectorized may only be vectorized over one argument, not all arguments. You just have to read the help pages for each function. See what it expects for each argument in the "Arguments" section and read what it returns in the "Value" section.