# Syntax error in ggplot Function in R

Tags: r, function, plot, ggplot2, syntax-error

I wanted to create automatic plot function by using following code:

```
plotTimeSeries <- list(temp1,temp2)

lapply(1:length(plotTimeSeries) , function(i) 
i$dt=strptime(i$dt, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
ggplot(i, aes(dt, ambtemp)) + geom_line() +
  scale_x_datetime(breaks = date_breaks("2 hour"),labels=date_format("%H:%M")) + xlab("Time 00.00 ~ 24:00 (2007-09-29)") + ylab("Ambient Tempreture")+
  opts(title = ("Node i")))
```

But I faced with the error below:

```
Error: unexpected ')' in:
"           scale_x_datetime(breaks = date_breaks("2 hour"),labels=date_format("%H:%M")) + xlab("Time 00.00 ~ 24:00 (2007-09-29)") + ylab("Ambient Tempreture")+
           opts(title = ("Node i")))"
```

Sample data properties:

```
'data.frame':   731 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ ambtemp: num  0.23 0.26 0.35 0.31 0.32 0.3 0.36 0.33 0.27 0.27 ...
 $ dt     : POSIXct, format: "2007-09-29 23:39:05" "2007-09-29 23:41:05" "2007-09-29 23:43:05" ...
```

Sample data:

temp1:

```
 surtemp    date_time
1    0.23 2007-09-29 23:39:05
2    0.26 2007-09-29 23:41:05
3    0.35 2007-09-29 23:43:05
4    0.31 2007-09-29 23:45:05
5    0.32 2007-09-29 23:47:05
6    0.30 2007-09-29 23:49:05
```

temp2:

```
     surtemp    date_time
1   -1.42 2007-09-28 23:39:09
2   -1.24 2007-09-28 23:41:09
3   -1.28 2007-09-28 23:43:09
4   -1.28 2007-09-28 23:45:09
5   -1.24 2007-09-28 23:47:09
6   -1.42 2007-09-28 23:49:09
```

Comment: No, I don not think problem cased because of that ')' since it goes back to the lapply(. If I remove the opts ')' the coresponding '(' should also be removed. After removing both I came up with other errors.

Comment: if you want both expressions (setting `i$dt` and running `ggplot`) to be executed in the body of the function, you need curly brackets `{}` around them

Comment: @BenBolker, I have tried that as: plotTimeSeries <- list(n25_30,n25_29)

lapply{1:length(plotTimeSeries) , function(i) 
    i$dt=strptime(i$dt, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
       ggplot(i, aes(dt, ambtemp)) + geom_line() +
           scale_x_datetime(breaks = date_breaks("2 hour"),labels=date_format("%H:%M")) + xlab("Time 00.00 ~ 24:00 (2007-09-29)") + ylab("Ambient Tempreture")+
           opts(title = ("Node i"))}. However, the problem still exist.

Comment: No, the curly brackets go around the body of the *function*. Iterative syntax debugging is frustrating.  Can you please post a **reproducible example** http://tinyurl.com/reproducible-000 ?

Comment: unreproducible example is unreproducible. Try making it simpler and simpler and eventually you'll hit the one thing that is breaking it.

Comment: I'm giving up for now.  I've posted an answer that I think should fix it. Thanks for attempting to post data, but (1) your `temp1` and `temp2` aren't consistent with your "Sample data properties" (the column names are different), (2) you really should use `dput()` to make life easier for answerers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be less confusing to revert to a `for` loop. Try:

```
plotTimeSeries <- list(temp1,temp2,temp3,temp4)
for (i in plotTimeSeries) {
   i$dt <- strptime(i$dt, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
   ggplot(i, aes(dt, ambtemp)) + geom_line() +
     scale_x_datetime(breaks = date_breaks("2 hour"),
                      labels=date_format("%H:%M")) + 
       labs(x="Time 00.00 ~ 24:00 (2007-09-29)",y="Ambient Temperature",
           title = (paste("Node",i)))
}
```

Comment: Now, I faced with this error:     'opts' is deprecated. Use 'theme' instead. (Deprecated; last used in version 0.9.1)
Setting the plot title with opts(title="...") is deprecated.
 Use labs(title="...") or ggtitle("...") instead. (Deprecated; last used in version 0.9.1)
'opts' is deprecated. Use 'theme' instead. (Deprecated; last used in version 0.9.1)
Setting the plot title with opts(title="...") is deprecated.
 Use labs(title="...") or ggtitle("...") instead. (Deprecated; last used in version 0.9.1)

Comment: did you try switching from `opts` to `theme` as suggested by the error message???(!)??? (I edited my answer)

Comment: But by using theme I cannot utilize 'i'. I came up with a new error:  Error in function (el, elname)  : 
  Element title must be a element_text object.

Comment: I'm sorry, someone else will have to help you.  I can't keep doing this without a **reproducible example**.  Good luck ...

Comment: The code ran without error, thankss. But the results are not presented.

Comment: Maybe if you give a reproducible example (hint, hint) someone will show you how to solve your problem ...

Comment: @Topdombili: It's an R-FAQ that inside for-loops you need to `print` the ggplot object.