# Promises in lapply / R

Tags: r, binding, higher-order-functions

I am not sure what the promises are doing in R

If one runs

```
a = lapply(seq_len(2), function(n) { function() {n}})
b = lapply(seq_len(2), function(n)  {n})
```

we can see that

```
a[[1]]() # == 2
b[[1]]   # == 1
```

I understand that R uses [promise's object](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Promise-objects) and lazily evaluates an expression in its environment, but I dont understand why the different **environments** created for each function would not contain their own value for n.

```
[[1]]
function () 
{
    n
}
<environment: 0x7f9b2416ad18>

[[2]]
function () 
{
    n
}
<environment: 0x7f9b2416ab20>

as.list(environment(a[[1]])) 
$n
[1] 2

as.list(environment(a[[2]]))
$n
[1] 2
```

Is it be possible to fix the semantic through the lapply function somehow  ?

```
lapply
function (X, FUN, ...) 
{
    FUN <- match.fun(FUN)
    if (!is.vector(X) || is.object(X)) 
        X <- as.list(X)
    .Internal(lapply(X, FUN))
}
<bytecode: 0x7f9b25150f18>
<environment: namespace:base>
```

PS : refocused question

Edit : concretely, is it possible to write a **lapply2** function that generically "forces" the argument to have uniform behaviour as in :

```
pl <- lapply (1:3, function(y) { force(y); function(x) pow(x,y) } )
pl <- lapply2(1:3, function(y) { function(x) pow(x,y) } )
```

Comment: I'm kind of confused. Isn't it because each function's environment contains only the promise, not the value, which isn't evaluated until it's needed, as explained in your previous question?

Comment: Now you're comparing closures with values.  I'd say that's like apples vs. oranges, but  http://www.improbable.com/airchives/paperair/volume1/v1i3/air-1-3-apples.html .    So I'll just say "don't do it."

Comment: yes, the problem is not promises per se, as long as the environment is tracked adequately.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29

Comment: @vodka : that's exactly what it is about..

Comment: @joran normallly, the evaluation strategy does not matter for the result... barring reliance on side effect of course ! haskell make it very explicit for instance. performance guarantee can be tricky though  because of accumulated computation

Comment: My problem is that reading abount R scopes and closures and the help of force() the semantics does not seem broken to me.

Comment: @vodka It is a bit different than other langages, like Haskell or ML. There might be reason for it, but there are definitely  good reason against it as well. I guess it makes sense to have the choice.

Comment: found this comment here on the web : 
"i thought (based on some sections in one of the r manuals) that promises are intended to spare unnecessary computations without making the user aware of the mechanism.  thomas' solution above forces a user to explicitly operate on promises to achieve functional behaviour;  if the correction is not used, the promise mechanism becomes visible by the result.  in both ways, the mechanism is exposed, which seems (to me) to contradict the idea."

Comment: @CarlWitthoft of course, values and function are not the same, but it looks here that just delaying the value by a function application gives different value in the end. whereas I might expect, if I delay on one hand, and apply later, to get back the same number.

Comment: I thought to post an update - it seems like things have changed in R and the code snippets from the start of your question now do return the same result. I remember seeing the same in Hadley Wickham's Advanced R book where a code snippet warning about the dangers of promises was actually producing something else. To my understanding - lapply now probably forces its FUN arg similarly to your lapply2 suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

I find it easier to understand in this form:

```
f=function(n) {function() {n}}
x=1
a=f(x)
x=2
a()
[1] 2
```

The key part of the documentation is

> When a function is called the arguments are matched and then each of
>   the formal arguments is bound to a promise. The expression that was
>   given for that formal argument and a pointer to the environment the
>   function was called from are stored in the promise.

After the call `a=f(x)`, the function argument `n` is bound to a promise with the name `x` and a pointer to the global environment `.GlobalEnv`.

In your `lapply` examples, the anonymous function `function(n) { function() {n}}` is called from the global environment each time.  This is why every element of the list `a` gets the same value of `n`: it's coming from the global environment.  I don't see how it's possible to change this behaviour by rewriting lapply.

Comment: that is probably what happens. but that seems very odd with implementation of closures in other language. by definition a function should always return the same result when given the same arguments.

Answer (score 1):

I posted a comment a while ago that this might be the case as of recent versions of `R` but here is an offical proof as well that `lapply` now behaves exactly like your `lapply2` version, taken from the [news release of `R` 3.2.0](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-announce/2015/000583.html).

- Higher order functions such as the apply functions and Reduce() now force arguments to the functions they apply in order to eliminate undesirable interactions between lazy evaluation and variable capture in closures.  This resolves PR#16093.

Comment: This is great ! thank you for mentioning it. then it will more like regular functional languages which preserve lexical scope after closure. great success