# How do I select rows with conditions on multiple columns in R

Tags: r

I have a table as given below:

```
dput(tail(dt[,c("DSALENew","PPEGTNew","ACNew")],5)) 

structure(list(DSALENew = c(1.2, 1.54, 1.1, 12, 1.1), 
PPEGTNew = c(4, 1.2, 2.2, 1.1, 2), ACNew = c(458, 1.2, 1.5, 
1.88, 3.2)), .Names = c("DSALENew", "PPEGTNew", "ACNew"), row.names = c(139728L,  139730L, 139731L, 139732L, 139733L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to select only those rows which has values between 1 and 2 for columns DSALENew and PPEGTNew. How can I do the same? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for all the solution. But let say I say 20 such columsn to do the filtering for. How to do the same for 20 columns? Let say colnames is the list of columns to do the filtering for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An other way : with `subset` and `%between%` operator by mrip :

```
`%between%`<-function(x,rng) x>rng[1] & x<rng[2]
subset(x, DSALENew %between% c(1,2) & PPEGTNew %between% c(1,2))

##        DSALENew PPEGTNew ACNew
## 139730     1.54      1.2   1.2
```

But be careful of what you want : `>` or `>=`

If you have several variables and only one condition for all the variable you could do :

```
## Data
set.seed(85)
x <- as.data.frame(matrix(round(runif(1000, min=1, max=3), 3), ncol=10))
## Condition applied on each column
index <- sapply(1:ncol(x), function(i) x[, i] %between% c(1,2))
## For which row the condition is true for all column
index <- apply(index, 1, all)
x[index, ]

##      V1    V2    V3    V4    V5    V6    V7    V8    V9   V10
## 3 1.573 1.403 1.128 1.333 1.011 1.697 1.407 1.626 1.656 1.237
```

Answer (score 2):

call that data.frame x

```
x[x$DSALENew >=1 & x$DSALENew <=2 & x$PPEGTNew >=1 & x$PPEGTNew <=2,]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
> library(dplyr)
> filter(df, DSALENew > 1, DSALENew < 2, PPEGTNew > 1, PPEGTNew < 2)
  DSALENew PPEGTNew ACNew
1     1.54      1.2   1.2
```

Comment: `for(i in 1:2) {
  df <- df[df[,i] < 2 & df[,i] > 1,] 
}
`

Comment: something like this? ^^^

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275896/is-rs-apply-family-more-than-syntactic-sugar

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that `dat` is your data frame.

You can use the following check

```
check <- rowMeans(dat[,1:2] > 1 & dat[,1:2] < 2) == 1
dat[check,]
```