# Use a vector to create empty columns in a data frame

Tags: r

I currently have a integer vector `exampleVector`, and a data frame `exampleDF`, and I would like to add each element of `exampleVector` as a new column, whose elements are NA, in the data frame `exampleDF`.  For illustration, I currently have:

```
exampleVector <- 1:6
exampleDF <- data.frame(First=1:4, Second=4:7,Third=7:10)
exampleDF
  First Second Third  
1     1      4     7  
2     2      5     8  
3     3      6     9  
4     4      7    10
```

And what I would like to be able to create is

```
exampleDF
  First Second Third    1    2    3    4    5    6
1     1      4     7 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
2     2      5     8 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
3     3      6     9 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
4     4      7    10 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
```

Where `exampleDF[4:9]` are character vectors.

I am aware that I would be able to do this using variations of the below commands:

```
exampleDF$"1" <- as.character(NA)
exampleDF[["1"]] <- as.character(NA)
exampleDF[c("1","2","3","4","5","6")] <- as.character(NA)
```

But I need something that is more flexible.  Everything that I've been able to find online has been about adding one column to multiple data frames, and to do so they suggest `mapply` and `cbind`.

My apologies if I'm missing something obvious here - I am very new to the R language and I'm trying to do this without a `for` loop, if possible, as recent interactions have led me to believe that this is mostly considered a hack in R scripts, as the apply functions are typically sufficient.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by flexible? Because your last example doesn't require an explicit for loop

Comment: is this flexible enough? exampleDF[as.character(exampleVector)] <- NA_character_

Comment: how was `exampleDF[c("1","2","3","4","5","6")] <- as.character(NA)` not flexible enough and @chinsoon12 how is yours different than what the OP already has?

Comment: @rawr his exampleVector is type integer. And he is typing the number one by one as a character in OP.

Comment: @chinsoon12 you're telling me op can `as.character(NA)` but not `as.character(exampleVector)` ? I don't believe that

Comment: Just a short remark on the last sentence: The `*apply` functions are wrappers for `for` loops; they are more compact and less error-prone than `for` loops, but they are usually not faster. It is true that `for` loops should generally be avoided in R, but the goal should be to exploit the vectorized capabilities of R, and not to use `apply` instead of `for`. More information [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2276001/4770166).

Comment: Naming columns with integers is asking for trouble downstream

Comment: This was just an example, the final state is for `exampleVector` to be UUIDs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your `exampleVector` is numeric, you should convert it to
characters when you enter it into the code.  Otherwise it will be
interpreted as a selection based on indexes.

```
exampleVector <- 1:6
exampleDF <- data.frame(First=1:4, Second=4:7,Third=7:10)


exampleDF[as.character(exampleVector)] <- NA_character_
```

Note that there's no restriction in this setup that protects you
against getting a data frame with the same name occurring several
times.  That might create problems later on (if you want to subset
your data frame by names), so I would have added a sanity check to
ensure that you do get unique names.

Comment: There we go - I was trying `exampleDF[exampleVector] <- as.character(NA)` and getting into all kinds of trouble.  I didn't realize that it would take `exampleVector` and treat it as an index because it's an integer vector.