# R: How to do this without a for-loop?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, vectorization

The following code in R uses a for-loop.  What is a way I could solve the same problem without a for-loop (maybe by vectorizing it)?

I am looking at an unfamiliar dataset with many columns (243), and am trying to figure out which columns hold unstructured text.  As a first check, I was going to flag columns that are 1) of class 'character' and 2) have at least ten unique values.

```
openEnded <- rep(x = NA, times = ncol(scaryData))
for(i in 1:ncol(scaryData)) {
  openEnded[i] <- is.character(scaryData[[i]]) & length(unique(scaryData[[i]])) >= 10
  }
```

Comment: You may well be able to avoid loops, and vectorise this, but really need to see a small example of your data. Can you share, for example, `dput(scaryData[1:5])` please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would probably do the job:

```
openEnded <- apply(scaryData, 2, function(x) is.character(x) & length(unique(x))>=10)
```

From the loop, you simply iterate over columns (that's the `apply(scaryData, 2`) part) an anonymous function that combines your two conditions (`function(x) cond1 & cond2`).

I guess your data is a `data.frame` so `sapply(scaryData, 2, function(x) ...)` would also work.

A nice post about the `*apply` family can be found [there](http://www.r-bloggers.com/using-apply-sapply-lapply-in-r/).

Comment: Thank you!  This would not be considered "vectorizing" the operation, since it does not explicitly use matrix algebra, correct?

Comment: @JohnFogg No, it is not vectorized. [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275896/is-rs-apply-family-more-than-syntactic-sugar/2276001#2276001) could be of interest.