# R apply-like function for updating 2 arrays simultaneously?

Tags: arrays, r, vector, apply

I am new to R, and looking for an apply type function to work with 2 arrays at once (simultaneous update).

For example, let's say I have some variables X and P:

```
X = array(rep(0, 10), dim=c(10, 1))
P = array(rep(1, 10), dim=c(10, 1))
```

which are governed by the system of equations:

```
X[k,] = 2*X[k-1]
P[k,] = 3*X[k] + X[k-1] + 3
```

Obviously, this can easily be accomplished with a for-loop, however, I have read/confirmed myself that for loops work horrendously for large inputs, and I wanted to start getting into good R coding practice, so I am wondering, what is the best way to do this in an apply-type logic? I am looking for something like,

```
sapply(2:dim(X)[1], function(k) {
    X[k,] = 2*X[k-1]
    P[k,] = 3*X[k] + X[k-1] + 3
})
```

But this obviously won't work, as it doesn't actually update X and P internally. Any tips/tricks for how to make my for-loops faster, and get in better R coding practice? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It appears all values of `X` will be 0, what am I missing ?

Comment: Many times, the assertion that `for` loops are *evil* is misplaced. What code and what benchmarks do you have to substantiate your claim that *"for loops work horrendously for large inputs"*? R has made great strides in the last few years in this arena, and though I'm a big fan in the `apply` family of functions *when it makes sense*, I also realize that sometimes the shoe-horn is a little too aggressive.

Comment: do not use apply but vectorization, for example on `X`: `head(X,1)*(2^seq(nrow(X)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following below.  The `<<-` operator will set `X` and `P` outside of the function

```
sapply(2:dim(X)[1], function(k) {
    X[k,] <<- 2*X[k-1]
    P[k,] <<- 3*X[k] + X[k-1] + 3
})
```

As pointed out by thelatemail in the comments, using `<<-` can be problematic because of the side effects it can have.  See the links below, the one comparing `for` loops (and other loops) to the `apply` family of functions.

Here is a link to documentation on [assignment operators](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/assignOps.html) in R.

Here is a StackOverflow link on [for loop vs. apply functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275896/is-rs-apply-family-more-than-syntactic-sugar) that talks about performance.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Using `<<-` is just asking for trouble. Why not just use `<-` in an old school loop `for( k in 2:dim(X)[1]) {X[k,] <- 2*X[k-1]; P[k,] <- 3*X[k] + X[k-1] + 3}` ? I'd be amazed if it was any slower in real terms.

Comment: @thelatemail My answer was mainly focused on answering how one could update the variables outside of a somewhat simple `sapply` in a simple coding situation (that is what was being asked).  However, as a general practice for a little more complex code, changing variables outside the scope of the function can be problematic (as you had mentioned).  In other words, I agree it is good to avoid it.

Comment: @thelatemail FYI, I just added a link to a SO post which talks about "for loops" vs. the "apply" family of functions.