# R nested for multiple if loops to generate new vector

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, for-loop, probability

I have 20 workers doing 100 tasks each. I have generated the true answer for each task, which is 1 out of 5 answers by

```
answers <- c("liver", "blood", "lung", "brain", "heart")
truth <- sample(answers, no.tasks, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2))
```

My dataSet contains the columns workerID, taskID, truth. Now I need to generate another vector where I am simulating what the worker will answer based on a certain probability. For example, if my truth for task 1, worker 1 is "liver", I want the worker 1 to answer "liver" for task 1 with a high probability. Similarly for each of the five answers for all the 2000 tasks, I want the workers answers. For that I am using the following for and if loops.

```
for (i in nrow(dataSet)){
if (dataSet$truth[i] == "liver")
{
df <- (rep(sample(answers, no.tasks, prob = c(0.9, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02), no.workers)))
} else if (dataSet$truth[i] == "blood")
{ 
df <-  (rep(sample(answers, no.tasks, prob = c(0.02, 0.9, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02), no.workers)))
} else if (dataSet$truth[i] == "lung")
{
df <- (rep(sample(answers, no.tasks, prob = c(0.02, 0.02, 0.9, 0.02, 0.02), no.workers)))
} else if (dataSet$truth[i] == "brain")
{
df <- (rep(sample(answers, no.tasks, prob = c(0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.9, 0.02), no.workers)))
} else if (dataSet$truth[i] == "heart")
{
df <-  (rep(sample(answers, no.tasks, prob = c(0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.9), no.workers)))
} else {
df <- (rep(sample(answers, no.tasks, prob = c(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2), no.workers)))
}
}
```

But, since my truth for task 1 is brain, the output vector df has a lot of answers which are "brain". Can some one please hint as to what is going wrong here?

Comment: I haven't tried running your code yet, but looking at it, it doesn't look like you are actually storing your result each round, but are instead overwriting `df` everytime.  Try adding a statement at the top `df <- matrix(nrow = nrow(dataSet), ncol = no.tasks)` and make your assignments `df[i, ] <- ...`

Comment: Please show expected output. Only one vector? One vector per answer per task?

Comment: @Parfait yes I want only one vector as the output

Comment: And what should that vector look like given example data? This helps us reproduce.

Comment: @Barker I did that but its giving me NA as the values :/.

Comment: @Parfait just a vector of 2000 (20 workers*100 tasks) values with either one of the five answers
    > df
    [1] "liver" "heart" "blood" "lung"  "lung"  "lung"  "liver" "blood" "lung"  "blood" "heart"
  [12] "blood" "blood" "lung"  "liver" "brain" "brain" "lung"  "liver" "lung"  "lung"  "blood"
  [23] "liver" "lung"  "heart" "heart" "blood" "liver" "lung"  "brain" "brain" "blood" "blood"
....

Comment: ok so I changed 2 things: 1. I added df <- vector(mode="character", length=2000) and 2. for (i in 1:nrow(dataSet)), the 1: was missing. When I run the loop, I get a vector that I want but then I get this warning: 
In df[i] <- (rep(sample(answers, no.tasks, prob = c(0.02,  ... :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
But, this is ok to ignore, right? because I am replace each value in the same vector?

Comment: Also, can I do this without a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider initializing with a list that carries underlying character vector of 1,000 elements.

```
df <- vector("list", 2000) 

for (i in 1:nrow(dataSet)){
if (dataSet$truth[i] == "liver")
{
df[[i]] <-(rep(sample(answers, no.tasks, prob = c(0.9, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02), no.workers)))
} else if (dataSet$truth[i] == "blood")
{ 
df[[i]] <-(rep(sample(answers, no.tasks, prob = c(0.02, 0.9, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02), no.workers)))
} else if (dataSet$truth[i] == "lung")
{
df[[i]] <-(rep(sample(answers, no.tasks, prob = c(0.02, 0.02, 0.9, 0.02, 0.02), no.workers)))
} else if (dataSet$truth[i] == "brain")
{
df[[i]] <-(rep(sample(answers, no.tasks, prob = c(0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.9, 0.02), no.workers)))
} else if (dataSet$truth[i] == "heart")
{
df[[i]] <-(rep(sample(answers, no.tasks, prob = c(0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.9), no.workers)))
} 
}
```

Alternatively, you can use `lapply()` that will output the same length list vector as the input (i.e., rows of *dataSet*), not requiring initialization:

```
df2 <- lapply(seq_len(nrow(dataSet)), function(i){
  if (dataSet$truth[i] == "liver")
  {
  temp <- (rep(sample(answers, no.tasks, prob = c(0.9, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02), no.workers)))
  } else if (dataSet$truth[i] == "blood")
  { 
  temp <- (rep(sample(answers, no.tasks, prob = c(0.02, 0.9, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02), no.workers)))
  } else if (dataSet$truth[i] == "lung")
  {
  temp <- (rep(sample(answers, no.tasks, prob = c(0.02, 0.02, 0.9, 0.02, 0.02), no.workers)))
  } else if (dataSet$truth[i] == "brain")
  {
  temp <- (rep(sample(answers, no.tasks, prob = c(0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.9, 0.02), no.workers)))
  } else if (dataSet$truth[i] == "heart")
  {
  temp <- (rep(sample(answers, no.tasks, prob = c(0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.9), no.workers)))
  } 
  return(temp)
})
```

Even better, you can trim down the nested `if` statements by matching the current `dataSet$truth` in *answers* vector, and then replacing the corresponding index in the probability vector with *0.9*:

```
df3 <- lapply(seq_len(nrow(dataSet)), function(i){
  probs <- c(0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.2)      
  probs[match(dataSet$truth[i], answers)] <- 0.9

  temp <- (rep(sample(answers, no.tasks, prob = probs, no.workers)))
})
```

Comment: Yes, thank you the lapply function is exactly what I wanted. That works well and gets rid of the loop, which is perfect because I will be working with larger data.

Comment: Great! Please accept if answer helped and confirms resolution. Also, `lapply()` is technically still a loop but a vectorized one and provides more clarity. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275896/is-rs-apply-family-more-than-syntactic-sugar

Comment: question: After I get the answers, I want to compare it with the answers from the dataSet to calculate the inter-rater agreement i.e. the kappa value. But, when I run this program a 100 times, I get some of the irr's to be negative. Do you have a clue as to why they would be negative?

Comment: That might need to be a new question as I am not aware of your *irr* process.