# R -- loop through files and create output table

Tags: r, function, loops

I need to perform a series of calculations from several files and create a single output table with the results from all files.

I have tried by listing all files within folder and looping, either with `for` or with `lapply` functions but there is something I am missing.

Here is a simplified vs of what I have with some 'fake' files:

```
# Create new folder -- "trials"
setwd("C:/Users/.../Desktop")
dir.create("trials")

# Create 'trial' files
setwd("C:/Users/.../Desktop/trials")
pathFiles <- "C:/Users/.../Desktop/trials"

df_1 <- data.frame(x=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10))
df_1$y <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
df_1$z <- c(10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100)
write.table(df_1, "table1.csv", col.names = TRUE, row.names = FALSE, sep = ",")

df_2 <- data.frame(x=c(2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11))
df_2$y <- c(2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11)
df_2$z <- c(20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,110)
write.table(df_2, "table2.csv", col.names = TRUE, row.names = FALSE, sep = ",")

df_3 <- data.frame(x=c(3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12))
df_3$y <- c(3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)
df_3$z <- c(30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,110,120)
write.table(df_3, "table3.csv", col.names = TRUE, row.names = FALSE, sep = ",")
```

For each of these files, I want to extract certain information and create an output table with all calculated fields.

I've tried with `for` loop:

```
Final <- NULL
M <- NULL
slp <- NULL
eval <- NULL

dfs <- dir(pathFiles, "*.csv", full.names = TRUE, ignore.case = TRUE, all.files = TRUE)

for (df in dfs) {

  t <- read.csv(df, header = TRUE, sep = ",")
  x <- t$x
  y <- t$y
  z <- t$z

  lim_y <- y >= 3 & y <=6
  lim_x <- x[lim_y]
  lim_z <- z[lim_y]

  iFinal <- x[nrow(t)]
  Final <- c(Final, iFinal) # add value to the string

  iM <- mean(lim_z)
  M <- c(M, iM) # add value to the string

  p <- lm(lim_x ~ lim_z)
  iSlp <- summary(p)$coefficients[2,1]
  slp <- c(slp, iSlp) # add value to the string

  ifelse ((Slp <= 0.05 & Slp >= -0.05), ieval <- "ok", ieval <- "false") 
  eval <- c(eval, ieval) # add value to the string
}

sum_df <- data.frame(df, M, Slp, eval, Final)
write.table(sum_df, "sum_df.csv", sep = ",", row.names = FALSE, col.names = TRUE)
```

I have used this `for` loop in a similar way before and it worked fine, but not here.

With an `lapply` function I do not get better results:

```
dfs <- list.files(pathFiles, "^.+\\.csv", full.names = TRUE, ignore.case = TRUE, all.files = TRUE)

Final <- NULL
M <- NULL
slp <- NULL
eval <- NULL

model <- function(x){
  t <- read.csv(x, header = TRUE, sep = ",")
  x <- t$x
  y <- t$y
  z <- t$z

  lim_y <- y >= 3 & y <=6
  lim_x <- x[lim_y]
  lim_z <- z[lim_y]

  iFinal <- x[nrow(t)]
  Final <- c(Final, iFinal)

  iM <- mean(lim_z)
  M <- c(M, iM)

  p <- lm(lim_x ~ lim_z)
  iSlp <- summary(p)$coefficients[2,1]
  slp <- c(slp, iSlp)

  ifelse ((Slp <= 0.05 & Slp >= -0.05), ieval <- "ok", ieval <- "false") 
  eval <- c(eval, ieval)
}

lapply(dfs, model)
```

The functions and output table works fine with just one file, so I guess the error must be in how I am looping through the files. But I don't know where I'm going wrong.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: I've just run your for loop, and the only issue I see is a case issue with `slp` and `Slp`.  After adjusting that on my end, the loop completed successfully.  Otherwise, check to ensure that how you have `pathFiles` defined is a legitimate directory, and that your files actually do exist in that directory.

Comment: I changed that as you suggested but it is not working for me. I get the following error message: `Error in data.frame(df, M, Slp, eval, Final) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0`. All files are in the pointed directory, so not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Good completely-reproducible question, by the way. It made it easier to give it a quick try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You reference `slp` and `Slp`, so there's a typo somewhere. Doing a global replacement for one of them fixes that bug.

Your `for` loop does not produce an error for me.

Your `lapply` is wrong on a few notes:

- in general, one of the benefits of using `*apply` functions is that they work without [side-effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)), which is what you are doing within your `for` loop, and what you are setting up for when you globally assign `eval` and friends. Without trying to reach "out" from within `lapply` and assigning to the variables in the global namespace, your assignments to `M` and friends are silently discarded when the function exits. When you think of using these apply functions (and they are great), you should almost always assume that their universe completely disappears when the function exits, and they cannot exit. If you're a Trekkie, think of [Remember Me (Star Trek TNG)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remember_Me_(Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation)), where Beverly's universe is only what is within the bubble. (It is possible to pierce it, both in R and in the tv show.)
- Your function returns only `eval`, and that is only by accident. If you want to return all of the things you've highlighted as "interesting", then you need to explicitly return them, perhaps as a `list` or `data.frame`. (Not `vector`, as `ieval` will up-convert all vars to `character`.)

So don't think about concatenating data within `lapply`, think of keeping the results well-structured and combining later. Try this:

```
model2 <- function(fname) {
  dat <- read.csv(fname, header = TRUE, sep = ",")
  lim_y <- dat$y >= 3 & dat$y <=6
  lim_x <- dat$x[lim_y]
  lim_z <- dat$z[lim_y]

  iFinal <- dat$x[nrow(dat)]
  iM <- mean(lim_z)

  p <- lm(lim_x ~ lim_z)
  iSlp <- summary(p)$coefficients[2,1]

  iEval <- (iSlp <= 0.05 & iSlp >= -0.05) 

  return(data.frame(
    fname = fname,
    M = iM, Slp = iSlp, Eval = iEval, Final = iFinal,
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
}

do.call(rbind, lapply(dfs, model2))
# Warning in summary.lm(p) :
#   essentially perfect fit: summary may be unreliable
# Warning in summary.lm(p) :
#   essentially perfect fit: summary may be unreliable
# Warning in summary.lm(p) :
#   essentially perfect fit: summary may be unreliable
#          fname  M Slp  Eval Final
# 1 ./table1.csv 45 0.1 FALSE    10
# 2 ./table2.csv 45 0.1 FALSE    11
# 3 ./table3.csv 45 0.1 FALSE    12
```

There are countless ways to do this with the `*apply` family, but I think this is a decent one.

For some decent reading about `*apply`, frames within `list`s, and such, see:

- [apply vs loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275896/is-rs-apply-family-more-than-syntactic-sugar/2276001#2276001)
- [list of frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499013/how-do-i-make-a-list-of-data-frames/24376207#24376207)
- [apply family](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505701/grouping-functions-tapply-by-aggregate-and-the-apply-family)

Comment: great! thanks!! for some reason `for` loop is not working for me, but this works great! I did something similar but the `combine` bit was driving me crazy. I'll keep on trying with the `for` loop anyway; now it's just bugging me! Thanks again!

Comment: BTW the Trekkie tip was quite enlightening, and I am not kidding. I learned a lot, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend rbindlist in the data.table library.

lapply will return a list of length files,
rbindlist this list together into a single table

```
library(data.table)
files <- dir(pathFiles, "*.csv", full.names = TRUE, ignore.case = TRUE, all.files = TRUE)
desiredTable <- rbindlist(
                          lapply(
                                 files,
                                 function(x){
                                 fileData <- fread(x)
                                 CalculatedData <- ...do stuff...
                                 return(CalculatedData)
                                 }
                                )
                            )
```

Here is a working example using do.call, avoiding the use of data.table

```
numFiles <- 100 #number of random files to generate

# Generate a bunch of .csv with a fileID, some letters, and some numbers and put those files in the working dir
sapply(
  1:numFiles,
  function(f){
    dataReplicates <- 12
    dataLetters <- sample(LETTERS,12)
    dataNumbers <- sample(seq(1:100),12)
    fileID <- rep(f,dataReplicates)
    fileData <- cbind(
      fileID,
      dataLetters,
      dataNumbers
    )
    write.csv(
      fileData,
      paste0(getwd(),"/",Sys.Date(),"_",f,".csv"),
      row.names = FALSE
    )
   }
  )

# Read those files back in and store the names in a vector
thoseRandFiles <- dir(
  path = getwd(),
  pattern = as.character(Sys.Date()),
  full.names = TRUE
)

#using lapply and rbind, read in each file, perform operations, and bind into a single table
desiredTable <- do.call(
      rbind,
       lapply(
       thoseRandFiles,
        function(x){
         fileData <- read.csv(x)
         fileID <- fileData$fileID[1]
         firstLetter <- as.character(fileData$dataLetters[1])
         sumNumbers <- sum(fileData$dataNumbers)
         calData <- cbind.data.frame(fileID,firstLetter,sumNumbers)
         return(calData)
         }
       )
      )
```

Comment: Lacking the want/need for a `DT` object, perhaps just `do.call(rbind, lapply(...))`.

Comment: @r2evans you're right. I tend to operate with `DT` almost by default. Your recommendation would accomplish the same in base

Comment: @SubstantiaN and @r2evans thank you so much. Still missing something though. Maybe is the way I am entering the queries. It says "args" is missing. Is the first time I use `function(x)` and probably not structuring it well. I'll have to play with it a little.

Comment: @r2evans, I hate to ask for this but would you mind posting the code as you would to run the script? I keep getting the `argument "args" is missing, with no default` error message, and it feels I am going in circles. I know it's basic, so I'd understand if you don't. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @ SubstantiaN thank you very much. Nice approach! Following your suggestions, I did something quite similar but defining the `function` separately. However, the table I was getting showed the last file three times instead of one set of results for each file. I guess it had to do with how I was applying the `combine` function. Thanks again; this was so helpful.