# Default name of object passed to function by apply in R

Tags: r, apply

Say I have the following code:

```
# Create data frame
df <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b = 6:10)

#   a  b
# 1 1  6
# 2 2  7
# 3 3  8
# 4 4  9
# 5 5 10
```

Now, I print each row individually using `apply`

```
apply(df, MARGIN = 1, print)
```

If I wanted to reference a particular element of each row passed to `FUN` in `apply`, I'd do it by defining an anonymous function, like this:

```
apply(df, MARGIN = 1, function(x)print(x[1]))
```

This code just prints the first element in each row.

In the `tidyverse`, an object passed to a function via a pipe is by default referred to by `.`. If this was also the case for `apply`, I could write something along the lines of...

```
apply(df, MARGIN = 1, print(.[1]))
```

**My question**: can I refer to the object passed to `FUN` by a default name thus avoiding the need for a function definition (e.g., `function(x)`)?

Comment: You can't. BTW, you shouldn't use `apply` on `data.frame` objects.

Comment: Maybe look at the functions from `purrr`, you can use `~FUN(.x)`, instead of `function(x) FUN(x)`. `map_dfr(df[1], ~print(.x))` for example.

Comment: @nicola Okay, thanks. And presumably this extends to the apply family in general? (The no default name, I mean).

Comment: @G.Grothendieck So, your general point is that it's just easier to restructure/subset the data beforehand?

Comment: @RLave Thanks – I'll check that out.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275896/is-rs-apply-family-more-than-syntactic-sugar/2276001#2276001 see this for your first question, it extends to most of the `*apply`, not `lapply`

Comment: Yes. Have moved comment to an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1) restructure data** We can write:

```
apply(df[1], 1, print)
```

**2) gsubfn** One can also use fn$ in gsubfn.  In that case we can specify functions using formula notation.  The free variables, here just `x`, are assumed to be the arguments of the function.

```
library(gsubfn)
fn$apply(df, 1, ~ print(x[1]))
```

**3) magrittr** We can also do this:

```
library(magrittr)
df %>% apply(1, . %>% `[`(1) %>% print)
```

or

```
df %>% apply(1, . %>% extract(1) %>% print)
```

or

```
df %>% apply(1, . %>% { print(.[1]) } )
```

although you have to be careful in the case of the last one since the brace brackets are absolutely needed and the following does not work since it seems it interprets the second dot as `df` rather than the input to the anonymous function.

```
library(magrittr)
df %>% apply(1, . %>% print(.[1])) # wrong
```

Comment: I particularly like **2)**.