# How to combine for loop and uniroot in R?

Tags: r, loops

At first, I have two functions like the following:

```
ef <- function(x, a){
  if(a == 0){
    return(x)
  } else {
    return(1-exp(-a*(5+x)))
  }
}
```

```
f1 <- function(x) ef(x,a)-0.75*ef(2.5,a)-0.25*ef(-1,a)
```

If `a` is 2 (i.e. `a <- 2`), then the root should be:

```
uniroot(f1, c(-5, 0), tol = 0.0001)$root
```

Now my question is how to calculate the root of x of the function when `a` change from 0.05 to 3 by 0.05?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's more flexible to put `a` into `f1()` as an argument.

```
f1 <- function(x, a) ef(x, a)-0.75*ef(2.5, a)-0.25*ef(-1, a)
```

Then use `sapply()` to operate each value in the sequence `seq(0.05, 3, 0.05)`:

```
sapply(seq(0.05, 3, 0.05), function(A){
  uniroot(f1, c(-10, 10), tol = 0.0001, extendInt = "yes", a = A)$root
})

# [1]  1.565924900  1.503659791  1.438426382  1.370549617  1.300423929
# [6]  1.228478774  1.155273229  1.081323809  1.007194271  0.933431003 ...
```

The argument `extendInt = "yes"` can conquer the error when `f1()` does not have different signs at the endpoints. In addition, I prefer `apply` family rather than a `for` loop in this case. You can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2275896/10068985) for the reason.

---

**Edit:** `for` loop solution

```
a <- seq(0.05, 3, 0.05)
root <- numeric()
for(i in 1:length(a)){
  root[i] <- uniroot(f1, c(-10, 10), tol = 0.0001, extendInt = "yes", a = a[i])$root
}
```

At the end of the loop, the variable `root` will store all the roots. You can check whether the outputs of the two solutions are equal.

Comment: Can I ask why you set function(A)? Why is A?

Comment: The `A` in the function of `sapply()` is an argument I set to represent each value in the sequence 0.05 ~ 3. You can also use other texts but remember to change the argument inside.