# how can I count the serial number of a vector inside the lapply?

Tags: r, lapply

I have a big vactor (3GB) to process thru lapply, and I would like to know how much it has proceeded. It is easier if I can identify which element it is, but what if I can't?

In the `for` loop, I may assign a counter inside the loop, but how should I do to set a counter inside `lapply`?

```
X <- LETTERS[1:26]

lapply(X, function(a) {
  cat(paste0(which(X == a), "\r")
  print(a)
})
```

Many thanks.

Comment: `lapply` is little more than syntactic sugar over a for loop (although that [oversimplifies](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2275896/4996248) things). Why not just use a loop -- or (with 3GB) find a way to genuinely vectorize whatever it is that you are doing?

Answer (score 1):

To roll your own progress counter just iterate over `X`'s integer positions instead of iterating over `X`'s elements directly. The following prints the percentage processed:

```r
X_out <- lapply(seq_along(X), function(a) {
    cat("\r", round((a/length(X))*100), "%", sep = "")
    toupper(X[a])
})
```

You can also try the `progress` package. The only downside is that it seems to slow things down a bit (perhaps by design, so you can see the progress). You could try something like this:

```r
install.packages("progress")
library(progress)

X <- sample(letters, 100000, T)

pb <- progress_bar$new(total = length(X))

X_out <- lapply(X, function(a) {
    pb$tick()
    toupper(a)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the indexes rather than the vector itself:

```
X <- LETTERS
f <- function(i) {
  if (i %% 10 == 0) cat("X[", i, "] =", X[i], "\n")
  X[i]
}
result <- lapply(seq_along(X), f)
```

giving this output on the R console (as well as setting `result`):

```
X[ 10 ] = J 
X[ 20 ] = T
```

Alternately iterate over both the index and the vector:

```
f2 <- function(i, x) {
  if (i %% 10 == 0) cat("X[", i, "] =", x, "\n")
  x
}
result2 <- Map(f2, seq_along(X), X)
```