# Using functions of apply in R for implicit object

Tags: r, apply

I am processing a special object -- SliceData object from Matrix_eQTL -- in a loop and I am wondering if it can be re-write by any function in the "apply".

Let me explain it by a toy example. First I create the toy data by the following scripts.

```
library(MatrixEQTL)
set.seed(5)
gene_mat = matrix(data = rnorm(200000, mean=50, sd=10), nrow = 2000, ncol = 100)
gene = SlicedData$new(gene_mat);
gene$ResliceCombined(200)
```

Here I have a custom function `invnorm`.

```
invnorm <- function(expression){
  return(qnorm((rank(expression, na.last="keep") - 0.5)/sum(!is.na(expression))))
}
```

And what I want to do is to apply this `invnorm` on each row of each slice of `gene` object which can be realized by the following scripts

```
for( sl in 1:length(gene) ){
    mat = gene[[sl]]
    mat = t(apply(mat, 1, invnorm))
    gene[[sl]] = mat
}
```

So is there any way to re-wrote this loop by any function in the `apply` function family? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Would be easier if this were reproducible. as is ```lapply(gene, function (x) t(apply(x, 1, invnorm))``` should do this pretty well.

Comment: Good idea! Have added a toy example. May I have your suggestion in a formal solution so that I can upvote and accept it? Thank you very much!

Comment: This package uses S4 classes which means that usual ```lapply``` does not work. The good news is that your for loop should be just as fast as using ```lapply```. Plus, there's no shame in using a for loop as they are mainly there for readibility.

Comment: You revealed what I am thinking -- I am just shamed in using for loop lol. And thank you very much for your clear explanation! Do you mind just copy your comment to the answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, we could approach this by using `lapply` to replace your for loop.

```
gene = lapply(gene, function(sl) t(apply(sl, 1, invnorm)))
```

However, this package uses S4 classes which means that usual `lapply` does not work. The good news is that your for loop should be just as fast as using `lapply`. Plus, there's no shame in using a for loop - apply statements are mainly just syntatic sugar for readibility.

See also:

[Is R's apply family more than syntactic sugar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275896/is-rs-apply-family-more-than-syntactic-sugar)

Comment: Awesome! And a good review on both of apply family and for loop.