# Why is repeat, while and for so slow to start up?

Tags: r, performance, loops, microbenchmark

I was making some code optimizations where it seems that the `repeat`, `while` and `for` constructs seem to have quite some overhead on startup. Here is an example:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  {lapply(1:10, function(x) x)},
  {i <- 0; while (i < 10) i <- i + 1},
  {for (i in 1:10) i},
  {i <- 0; repeat if ((i <- i + 1) >= 10) break}
, times = 1000)
Unit: microseconds
                                            expr    min      lq     mean  median     uq      max neval
                 { lapply(1:10, function(x) x) }    7.4   12.80   15.101   14.30   15.5    919.9  1000
           { i <- 0; while (i < 10) i <- i + 1 } 1377.8 1431.85 1830.941 1475.10 1537.1  68344.9  1000
                           { for (i in 1:10) i }  838.0  880.00 1008.845  904.45  950.6  56744.9  1000
{ i <- 0; repeat if ((i <- i + 1) >= 10) break } 2092.4 2190.05 3265.421 2248.45 2343.2 467666.1  1000
```

If you use these constructs many times (e.g. within an outer loop), the 100x slower adds up considerably!

This seems contrary to my belief (and that of many [others](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2276001/1548942)). Am I missing something?

**Edit:** since I didn't see any effect in my real code, made me wonder...

```
f <- function(x) { i <- 0; repeat if ((i <- i + 1) >= x) break }
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  f(10L)  
, times = 1000)
Unit: nanoseconds
   expr min  lq  mean median  uq   max neval
 f(10L) 700 800 898.9    900 900 10700  1000
```

Note the nanoseconds! These are the times I expect from these constructs (e.g. mainly the overhead due to `<-`, `+` and `>=`). So it seems to be a problem with `microbenchmark`?

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)
```

Comment: @markus Note that question is about startup overhead of these constructs. A `C` function call in R is about 0.1 microseconds.I don't expect a `while` statement to take 1000x longer. The bigger picture is that if these constructs are used for short loops (e.g. `seq_len(10)`) then their overhead might add up considerably if the outer loop will execute it in the order of `seq_len(1e6)`.

Comment: FYI, two of your processes here work *a little* more: if you take the sequence `:` operator out, it's a more fair comparison (though not dramatically different).

Comment: @r2evans Yes, I was thinking about it. But it is one of those `C` calls: takes 0.1 microseconds. Same with `+` , `<-` and `>=`. You shouldn't see any effect.

Comment: @DavorJosipovic my guess would be that here we can see JIT (just-in-time) compilation taking effect. Where in your first examples each time the code is recompiled, but in second example only executed. But I am no expert in this...

Comment: When I run the original example code, I don't see the same level of slowness: fastest is ```for``` with mean 1184nanosecs, slowest is ```lapply``` with 10253nanosecs.  I'm running R 3.2.1 using RStudio.

Comment: Follow-up: Command-line vs RStudio doesn't seem to make a difference, but I now ran it on a server running R 3.6.2 (through command-line) and I indeed get a similar slowness as Davor: ```lapply``` mean 32microsecs, ```repeat``` 5645microsecs.  So it may arise from an 'optimization' in later versions of R.

Comment: @DominicvanEssen Good point. I added my platform info.

Comment: @r2evans, was thinking on that too, but consider this: `microbenchmark::microbenchmark((function(x) { i <- 0; repeat if ((i <- i + 1) >= x) break })(10))`.

Comment: Note (in R 3.6.2) that the dreaded add-up of overheads doesn't seem to happen: ```{ for(j in 1:10) j }``` runs in 2.2ms, but ```{for(i in 1:1000){ for(j in 1:10) j }}``` runs in 5.0ms (only 2x slower for 1000x iterations).  ```lapply``` behaves more conventionally: 1000x iterations takes ~1000x longer.