# Is there a way to calculate a multiple moving averages based on an ID and data frame in R?

Tags: r, statistics, average, moving-average

I am analyzing data and would like to calculate many moving averages at once. I will past here an example of what I am trying to do.

Table 1: IDs and Day

```
IDDate <- data.frame(ID = c("A","B","C"), 
Stage1 = c(12, 13, 10), 
Stage2 = c(14, 30, 12))
```

| ID | Stage 1 | Stage 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 12 | 14 |
| B | 13 | 30 |
| C | 10 | 12 |

Table 2: Daily Temperature Data

```
IDTemp <- data.frame(Day = c(1:12), 
A = c(-3,-2,1,4,2,3,10,15,5,4,6,4), 
B = c(-4,2,0,3,12,10,9,8,9,3,1,2), 
C = c(4,1,2,5,5,2,3,2,1,5,6,1))
```

| Day | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | -3 | -4 | 4 |
| 2 | -2 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 0 | 2 |
| 4 | 4 | 3 | 5 |
| 5 | 2 | 12 | 5 |
| 6 | 3 | 10 | 2 |
| 7 | 10 | 9 | 3 |
| 8 | 15 | 8 | 2 |
| 9 | 5 | 9 | 1 |
| 10 | 4 | 3 | 5 |
| 11 | 6 | 1 | 6 |
| 12 | 4 | 2 | 1 |

I would like to calculate the average of each temperature for each ID 4 days before the day listed in Table 1. That means, for stage 1, I would like the Temperature from A for days 9-12. If there is no temperature data for at least one of the days, then it should return an NA.

The result should look something like this.

Table 3: Desired Result

| ID | Stage 1 Temp | Stage 2 Temp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 4,75 | NA |
| B | NA | NA |
| C | 2,75 | 3,25 |

I have seen ways to calculate rolling averages based on specific end dates, but with multiple end dates I have not found anything. Apologies, however, if this is a duplicate topic.

Using rollmean in zoo I wasn't sure how to specify the necessary parameters to limit the average to being calculated only in specific (but varying) time windows.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved in `base R` with two "loops" (`sapply()`). All we need to do:

```r
IDDate <- data.frame(ID = c("A","B","C"), 
                     Stage1 = c(12, 13, 10), 
                     Stage2 = c(14, 30, 12))


IDTemp <- data.frame(Day = c(1:12), 
                     A = c(-3,-2,1,4,2,3,10,15,5,4,6,4), 
                     B = c(-4,2,0,3,12,10,9,8,9,3,1,2), 
                     C = c(4,1,2,5,5,2,3,2,1,5,6,1))

new_df <- t(
  sapply(X = unique(IDDate$ID), 
         FUN = \(id) { sapply(
           X = IDDate[IDDate$ID == id, 2L:3L], 
           FUN = \(j) mean( IDTemp[(j - 3L):j, id] ))
           }
         )
  )

new_df
#>   Stage1 Stage2
#> A   4.75     NA
#> B     NA     NA
#> C   2.75   3.25
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

We iterate over each `ID` and each `Stage` column. For each combination we calculate the mean of the specified 4-day window. We transpose the result to match the desired output format.
See these links: [comprehensive introduction to `*apply()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505701/grouping-functions-tapply-by-aggregate-and-the-apply-family) and a [comparison to explicitly written loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275896/is-rs-apply-family-more-than-syntactic-sugar/2276001#2276001).

(Best wishes from Berlin to Berlin.)

Answer (score 0):

We could write a function that does the job for specific day of specific id,

```
> ave_n_days <- \(id, d, n=4, data=IDTemp, tb=IDDate) {
+   dsq <- seq.int(from=d, to=d - n + 1, by=-1)
+   mh <- match(dsq, data$Day)
+   id <- match(id, names(data))
+   mean(data[mh, id])
+ }
> ave_n_days(id='A', d=12)
[1] 4.75
```

and use it in `by`.

```
> by(IDDate, ~ID, \(x) {
+   vapply(x[-1], 
+          FUN=\(d) ave_n_days(x$ID, d), 
+          FUN.VALUE=numeric(1))
+ }) |> do.call(what='rbind')
  Stage1 Stage2
A   4.75     NA
B     NA     NA
C   2.75   3.25
```

---

*Data:*

```
> dput(IDDate)
structure(list(ID = c("A", "B", "C"), Stage1 = c(12, 13, 10), 
    Stage2 = c(14, 30, 12)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
> dput(IDTemp)
structure(list(Day = 1:12, A = c(-3, -2, 1, 4, 2, 3, 10, 15, 
5, 4, 6, 4), B = c(-4, 2, 0, 3, 12, 10, 9, 8, 9, 3, 1, 2), C = c(4, 
1, 2, 5, 5, 2, 3, 2, 1, 5, 6, 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

Answer (score 0):

**1)** Convert `IDDate` to class `"zoo"` and compute the rolling means, `roll`. Then for each row of `IDDate` look up each day and ID in `roll`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

roll <- read.zoo(IDTemp) %>% rollmeanr(4)
IDDate %>%
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(across(-1, ~ coredata(roll)[match(.x, time(roll)), ID])) %>%
  ungroup
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 3 × 3
  ID    Stage1 Stage2
  <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 A       4.75  NA   
2 B      NA     NA   
3 C       2.75   3.25
```

**2)** Another possibility is to convert to long form and then join the data frames and convert back.

```
library (tidyr)
library(sqldf)

IDDateL <- pivot_longer(IDDate, -1, names_to = "Stage", values_to = "DayEnd")
IDTempL <- pivot_longer(IDTemp, -1, names_to = "ID")

long <- sqldf("select d.ID, d.Stage, iif(count(value) = 4, avg(value), NULL) mean
  from IDDateL d
  left join IDTempL t on d.ID = t.ID and
    t.Day between d.DayEnd - 3 and d.DayEnd
  group by d.ID, d.Stage")

pivot_wider(long, names_from = "Stage", values_from = "mean")
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 3 × 3
  ID    Stage1 Stage2
  <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 A       4.75  NA   
2 B      NA     NA   
3 C       2.75   3.25
```

### Note

Inputs from question:

```
IDDate <- data.frame(
  ID = c("A", "B", "C"), 
  Stage1 = c(12, 13, 10),
  Stage2 = c(14, 30, 12)
)

IDTemp <- data.frame(
  Day = 1:12,
  A = c(-3, -2, 1, 4, 2, 3, 10, 15, 5, 4, 6, 4),
  B = c(-4, 2, 0, 3, 12, 10, 9, 8, 9, 3, 1, 2),
  C = c(4, 1, 2, 5, 5, 2, 3, 2, 1, 5, 6, 1)
)
```